# trying to get property of non object and id on blog_post_tag = 0

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I'm having some problems with the code below. What I'm trying to do is to tell if a tag already exists in the table tags, if it does, get the `id` and put that `id` in the table blog_post_tags, or if it does not exist, create it, get the `id` and put it in blog_post_tags table. The problem is that, whenever I try to check if the `id` already exists, I get errors all over the place telling me `trying to get property of non object` but fields are still being insert in the other table with an `id` of `0` (which is not a valid id for the tags).

Here is the code:

```
foreach ($tags as $tag)
{
    //search for the tag to see if it exists 
    //the problem is located in this line of code
    if($select_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM tags WHERE name = ?"))
    {
        $select_stmt->bind_param("s",$tag);
        $select_stmt->execute();
        $result = $select_stmt->get_result();

        //if the tag exists
        if($select_stmt->num_rows != 0)
        {
            if($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO blog_post_tags (blog_post_id, tag_id) VALUES (?,?)"))
            {
                $insert_stmt->bind_param('ii', $blogid, $result);
                $insert_stmt->execute();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ($insert_stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tags (name) VALUES (?)")) 
            {
                $insert_stmt2->bind_param('s', $tag);
                $insert_stmt2->execute();
                $tagid = $mysqli->insert_id;

                if ($insert_stmt3 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO blog_post_tags (blog_post_id, tag_id) VALUES (?, ?)"))
                {
                    $insert_stmt3->bind_param('ii', $blogid, $tagid);
                    $insert_stmt3->execute();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

## EDIT

Some how, the "trying to get property of a non object" disappeared, i suspect it may have been a connection erro with the server but i really cant tell, still the table blog_post_tags is being filled with fields that does not make any sense, "tag_id =0". i suspect it may have something to do with the problem expressed here: [php prepared stmt problem- update data at each result loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193123/php-prepared-stmt-problem-update-data-at-each-result-loop?rq=1)
¿ how could i correct me code if the problem is related to that of the link above ?

Comment: Would be very helpful to comment the line where the error takes place.  Also which table is the "_other table_"?

Comment: ok i added extra information to the post, i'm sorry, the problem is located in the first prepared statement, but i dont know why, the name of the table is correct and field is correct too, so why would it fail ?, also, if it is failing, why is the "if($select_stmt->num_rows!= 0)" not catching this error ?

Comment: ok, what does the first execute say when using `var_dump($select_query->execute);`?

Comment: die(var_dump($select_stmt->execute()));
bool(true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i really dont know what it did, but it seem to have worked, here is the code without any errors:

```
foreach ($tags as $tag)
        {
            //search for the tag to see if it exists
            if ($select_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM tags WHERE name = ?")) 
            {

                $select_stmt->bind_param("s", $tag);
                $select_stmt->execute();
                $select_stmt->store_result();

                if ($select_stmt->num_rows() > 0) 
                {

                    $select_stmt->bind_result($tagid);
                    $select_stmt->fetch();
                    if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO blog_post_tags (blog_post_id, tag_id) VALUES (?, ?)"))
                    {
                        $insert_stmt->bind_param('ii', $blogid, $tagid);
                        $insert_stmt->execute();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if ($insert_stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tags (name) VALUES (?)"))
                    {
                        $insert_stmt2->bind_param('s', $tag);
                        $insert_stmt2->execute();
                        $tagid = $mysqli->insert_id;

                        if ($insert_stmt3 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO blog_post_tags (blog_post_id, tag_id) VALUES (?, ?)"))
                        {
                            $insert_stmt3->bind_param('ii', $blogid, $tagid);
                            $insert_stmt3->execute();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
         }
```

hopefully this can help anyone that encounters a similar problem, also, i would like to know if this solution is optimal or if there is any way to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

The error "trying to get property of non object" is probably because of a bad SQL statement. I suggest debug your script by echoing out your SQL statement used to search for the record and paste that output in your mysql console. Another thing that is worth mentioning, is that the column name of "id" does not work unless enclosed by tildas (`), so your statement should look like:

```
"SELECT `id` FROM `tags` WHERE `name` = '$name'"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks, but as you can see im trying to get this done by using prepared statements, for added security.